# Java Game slows down when adding background images

Tags: java, swing

I am having this problem whenever I load a background image no matter how small the size of the image. I am adding an image of 1010x600 png picture with a size of 3.81kb. I am using timer from swing in order to repaint this. The game just slows down whenever I add and paint the bg.paintIcon method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    bg.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
    p.img.paintIcon(null, g, p.x, p.y);
    g2p = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2p.setColor(Color.green);
    g2p.fillRect(20, 10, (int)Math.ceil((p.health/1000.0)*960), 20);
    life.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 8);

    g2p.setColor(Color.black);
    g2p.drawRect(19, 34, 960+1, 20+1);
    g2p.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2p.fillRect(20, 35, (int)Math.ceil((p.mana/500.0)*960), 20);

    //System.out.println(df.format(p.health/1000.0));
    jl.setLocation(p.x, p.y);
    //jl.setText("Current Health: "+p.health);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){//IMPORTANT
        g2[i] = (Graphics2D) g;
        e[i].img.paintIcon(null, g, e[i].getx(), e[i].gety());
        if (e[i].dead){
            gen[i] = new Thread(new Generation(i));
            if (letalive){
                letalive = false;
                gen[i].start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of class is this 'bg' object?

Comment: You're starting 20 threads every time `paintComponent()` is called which is like... what?  60 times a second or something?  Am I reading this right?  That's way too much.  EDIT:  Okay, it's not actually all that clear to me how often you're starting threads.  I don't know what `e` and `letalive` are.  But there are some suspicious things happening with threads here.

Comment: The *file size* of an image plays no role in how fast it draws. What matters is resolution and the pixel format in which it is stored in memory. So how do you load your image and whats the color depth of *image and screen*? Make sure these match

Comment: Likely its a translucent image too which in some situations / hardware configurations can be very slow to draw. Especially on integrated videocards. Are you running this on a laptop with an intel videocard perhaps? Did you try running on other computers to see if that makes a difference in how slow it is?

Comment: @Ben M. No. These classes are instantiated and an animated thread is started from it. Although the main problem here is that the image I am loading every time makes the program run slow.

Comment: Just to be sure, does the game is really running slow? or are you facing flickering? Maybe a DobleBuffered Image could be the solution if the problem is not game perfomance and it really is drawing image performance.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I run it in a laptop with intel graphics and I have tried it in a separate unit (computer), but the results are worse compare to my laptop (maybe that's because the unit I used is lower than my laptop). I'll try it in a unit which has better specs than my laptop. Thanks!

Comment: @rsan The changes in position of the objects are slower when the background image is loaded. Everything runs fine without it and I don't see any flicker (even with the bg loaded).

Comment: @BenM. Oh and another thing with 'letalive', It does not let 20 threads start in 1 for loop.but instead, it waits for the 'letalive' to be true first before starting that thread.

Answer (score 4):

Your paintComponent code should paint.  Period.  Nothing else.

Here's how your paintComponent method should look.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    bg.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
    p.img.paintIcon(null, g, p.x, p.y);
    g2p = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2p.setColor(Color.green);
    g2p.fillRect(20, 10, (int)Math.ceil((p.health/1000.0)*960), 20);
    life.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 8);

    g2p.setColor(Color.black);
    g2p.drawRect(19, 34, 960+1, 20+1);
    g2p.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2p.fillRect(20, 35, (int)Math.ceil((p.mana/500.0)*960), 20);

    //System.out.println(df.format(p.health/1000.0));
    jl.setLocation(p.x, p.y);
    //jl.setText("Current Health: "+p.health);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){//IMPORTANT
        e[i].img.paintIcon(null, g, e[i].getx(), e[i].gety());
    }
}
```

This code belongs in your controller.

```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
       if (e[i].dead){
            gen[i] = new Thread(new Generation(i));
            if (letalive){
                letalive = false;
                gen[i].start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JetMag Please consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer if it solved the problem, so users (maybe having a similar problem as you) will instantly know which was the most helpful answer.